# How to create custom bar button items on toolbars for xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't want to use the default buttons for my toolbar. I want to create my own. How should i go about doing this? I need to know the

- Sizes
- How to import them into the Xcode project. As in, do i put them in the assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom UIBarButtonItem using UIButton. Todo this, pass your UIButton as a parameter of UIBarButtonItem.

**Something like this:**

```
let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Take a look in my example:
[iOS-CustomButton](https://github.com/limadeveloper/iOS-CustomButton)